# Terraform Conditional Attribute

Tags: terraform, conditional-statements

Sorta stuck on this,
I am trying to use the RDS module [terraform-aws-modules](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds).

And I want the end user to be able to pass along `var.db_params` or `var.db_options` to `options = []` or parameters attribute, but if they don't pass anything then just default to null. This errors because the module is trying to do a `for_each` on "" or null which it can't.

Is there a way not to include the attributes for such if its null?

```
module "rds" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"

  identifier = var.name
  engine     = var.db_engine
  options    = var.db_options
  parameters = var.db_params
  # .....(removing all other code)
}

variable "db_params" {
  default = null
}

variable "db_options" {
  default = null
}
```

because the default is null i get:

```
Error: Invalid dynamic for_each value

var.options is ""
Cannot use a string value for_each. An iterable collection is required.
```

Sorry for the short code, but i cannot copy paste from this workspace.

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: @MarkoE added as much as i can type the code and error since i cannot copy paste from my remote workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing an empty string, or null, you should be passing an empty list:

```
variable "db_params" {
  default = []
}

variable "db_options" {
  default = []
}
```

Comment: This is correct, because you (not you but op) are overriding the default set [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/blob/master/variables.tf#L388). The alternative is to do a null check. `options = var.db_options != null ? var.db_options : []`

Comment: Damn, that was a horrible brain fart. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest getting into the habit of writing exact type constraints on your input variables. By giving Terraform more information about your intent you can help it to better explain problems in your code. In your case it seems like the most appropriate type constraint would be either `type = set(string)` or `type = list(string)`, depending on whether the ordering of these values is significant. Then Terraform can tell you earlier, inside the calling `module` block, that `""` is not an appropriate value to meet those type constraints.